# Does (django-) celery fork itself?

Tags: python, concurrency, celery, django-celery

Does celery fork itself for every task?
Lets say I have something like this:

```
obj = object()

@celery.task
def print_id():
   print id(obj)

#another server
print_id.delay()
print_id.delay()
print_id.delay()
```

When calling the task several times (without restarting celery), is the id always the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. See [concurency docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#concurrency).

If you set up at least two workers with `multiprocessing`, the `id` won't stay the same. Even if you use one node, and restart it after `X` task execution (an option in celery worker) the `id` won't stay the same.

Basically you shouldn't depend on that in your code. The very purpose of running tasks via **Celery** is distributing them.

May I ask why such question? Do you have any use case where you need that?

Comment: Thank you!
I just wanted to understand how our system works.
We have a global object holding a connector to an external system. This connector is created if it doesn't exist.
But from what you said, the connector won't be the same all the time. So we will have multiple connectors then.